# Deploying Keycloak on Kubernetes with Cloudflare Reverse Proxy

Tags: kubernetes, https, keycloak, cloudflare

I am working on a project where I'm deploying Keycloak on a Kubernetes (K8s) cluster, with Cloudflare serving as a reverse proxy using Cloudflare Tunnels. The architecture is set up as follows:

- A Cloudflare Tunnel  is configured to forward incoming HTTPS traffic from the domain `sso.example.com` to my Kubernetes cluster.
- Then, Ingress Controller in the Kubernetes cluster routes this incoming traffic to the Keycloak pod. This traffic is unencrypted (HTTP, port 8080)

The main Keycloak server is deployed as a container in the K8s cluster, with the Ingress configured to route traffic from the host at port 80 to Keycloak's cluster IP, which forwards traffic to the actual Keycloak pod serving at port 8080

Below are my K8s deployment config for keycloak

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  labels:
    app: keycloak
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: keycloak
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: keycloak
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: keycloak
        image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:21.0.2
        args: ["start"]
        env:
        - name: KC_PROXY
          value: "edge"
        - name: KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT
          value: "false"
        - name: KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_BACKCHANNEL
          value: "false"
        - name: KC_HOSTNAME
          value: "sso.example.com"
        - name: KC_HTTP_ENABLED
          value: "true"
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 8080
```

(Some env variables like DB configs are omitted for simplicity)

The problem I am having is that I am unable to access the admin console on my keycloak server using https despite being able to access the welcome page at `sso.example.com`. When accessing the admin console the page stuck at `Loading Admin UI` and console logs error `GET https://sso.example.com/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/login-status-iframe.html/init?client_id=security-admin-console&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fsso.example.com (403 Forbidden)`

I have seen https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/15107 but I am not sure how to set X-Forwarded-For header with Cloudflare tunnels

I have also tried adding

```
- name: KC_HOSTNAME_ADMIN
  value: "sso.example.com"
```

to the deployment config but still result in the same error.

However, if I deploy the server with `['start-dev']` instead of `['start']`, the 403 error is gone but with a new error of `Refused to frame 'http://sso.example.com/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src 'self'".` It seems like the iframe isn't being served with https despite that I have configured cloudflare to automatically rewrite all url to https.

Lastly, the admin console will load and work if I combine the option `['start-dev']` and change the cloudflare `SSL/TLS encryption mode` to `OFF` and accee the console with http.

I want to deploy with HTTPS while being able to access the admin console, please help.

Comment: I'm in a very similar boat, did you have any more luck with this?

Comment: @AlexanderFreyr Yes, I have fixed it but it was a while ago. Not exactly sure which option that made it work I think it's something relates to `KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_BACKCHANNEL`. Here is my entire config https://pastebin.com/njWvYZJS that is working. 
The rest of the setup I just have a ingress going to Keycloak at port 8080, and a cloudflare tunnel directing `sso.example.com` to my k8s ingress. I think the problem was microk8s/cloudflared not passing X-Forwarded-For headers to the Keycloak services.

Comment: Thanks, @sqz, that unfortunately didn't do the trick for my case but I appreciate the response :)

Comment: @AlexanderFreyr Hey man, I know it's been a while but are you still facing the problem, because I might have remembered what I did to make it work?

Comment: Hey! I did manage to get things working, unfortunately I don't remember what eventually resolved my issue after many trials and errors. It still might be helpful for others in the future if you post your potential solution